# Parallelise numerical integration in C++: OpenMP + boost ODEINT versus OpenMP + GSL integration

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing, numerical-integration

My objective is to parallelise a one-dimensional integral. I have looked around, and I would say that I could do that in two ways: i) implementing `OpenMP` with `ODEINT`, `boost` library `integrate_adapative` function (see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/parallel_computation_with_openmp_and_mpi.html).; ii) implementing `OpenMP` with `GSL` monte carlo integration (as in here: [Internal compiler error with nested functions in OpenMP parallel regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639432/internal-compiler-error-with-nested-functions-in-openmp-parallel-regions)).

My problem is that I cannot really understand what they did in both links I provided.
I was wondering whether someone has experience with that, and may point out how I could implement both approaches on my case. Is it `OpenMP` with `boost` faster or `GSL` and `OpenMP` implementation?

`PDFfunction` represents the probability density function that is used within the integrand function. `PDFfunction` is equivalent to [image], and in LateX is expressed as:

[image]

And this is how I code it:

```
double PDFfunction(double invL, int t, double invtau, double x0, double x, int n) {

const double c =  M_PI * (M_PI/4) * ((2 * t) * invtau);

double res = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++n){

  res += exp(-1 * (i * i) * c) * cos((i * M_PI * x) * invL) * cos((i * M_PI * x0) * invL);

}

return invL + ((2 * invL) * res);
}
```

`Composite_at_t` is a function that makes use of the `PDFfunction` to compute `pbA` and `pbB`. `Composite_at_t` is equivalent to [image], where [image]) and [image]).

[image]

```
double Composite_at_t(double t, double B, double x0, double xt_pos, double y0, double yt_pos, double invLtot, double invtau, int n_lim) {

double pbA = PDFfunction(invLtot, t, invtau, x0, xt_pos, n_lim);
double pbB = PDFfunction(invLtot, t, invtau, y0, yt_pos, n_lim);
double b1 = 2 * (2 * t) * exp(-2 * t * B);
return pbA * pbB * b1;
}
```

`Composite_at_tCLASS` is a Func class which computes a first integral over variable `t`.

```
class Composite_at_tCLASS: public Func{
private:
    double B;
    double x0;
    double xt_pos;
    double y0;
    double yt_pos;
    double invLtot;
    double invtau;
    int n_lim;
public:
    Composite_at_tCLASS(double B_, double x0_, double xt_pos_, double y0_, double yt_pos_, double invLtot_, double invtau_, int n_lim_) : B(B_), x0(x0_), xt_pos(xt_pos_), y0(y0_), yt_pos(yt_pos_), invLtot(invLtot_), invtau(invtau_), n_lim(n_lim_) {}
    double operator()(const double& t) const{
        return Composite_at_t(t, B, x0, xt_pos, y0, yt_pos, invLtot, invtau, n_lim);
    }
};
```

`integrate_CompositeCLASS` is the actual function that uses the class `Composite_at_tCLASS` and perform the integral over `t`, between `0` and `time_lim`.

```
double integrate_CompositeCLASS(double B, double x0, double xt_pos, double y0, double yt_pos, double invLtot, double invtau, int n_lim, double time_lim){

    Composite_at_tCLASS f(B, x0, xt_pos, y0, yt_pos, invLtot, invtau, n_lim);
    double err_est;
    int err_code;
    double res = integrate(f, 0, time_lim, err_est, err_code);
    return res;
}
```

For the numerical integration using the GSL library I would use the following code:

```
struct my_f_params { double B; double x0; double xt_pos; double y0; double yt_pos; double invtau; int n_lim; double invLtot;};

double g(double *k, size_t dim, void *p){
  struct my_f_params * fp = (struct my_f_params *)p;
  return Composite_at_t(k[0],fp->B, fp->x0, fp->xt_pos, fp->y0, fp->yt_pos, fp->invLtot, fp->invtau, fp->n_lim);
}
```

And this is the actual object that perform the GSL integral:

```
double integrate_integral(const double& invtau, const int& n_lim, const double& invLtot,
  const double& x0, const double& xt_pos, const double& y0, const double& yt_pos, const double& time_lim){

double res, err;

double xl[1] = {0};
double xu[1] = {time_lim};
const gsl_rng_type *T;
gsl_rng *r;

gsl_monte_function G;
struct my_f_params params = { B, x0, xt_pos, y0, yt_pos, invtau, n_lim, invLtot};

G.f = &g;
G.dim = 1;
G.params = &params;

size_t calls = 10000;

gsl_rng_env_setup ();

T = gsl_rng_default;
r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);


  gsl_monte_vegas_state *s = gsl_monte_vegas_alloc (1);
  gsl_monte_vegas_integrate (&G, xl, xu, 1, 10000, r, s,
                             &res, &err);

  do
        {
          gsl_monte_vegas_integrate (&G, xl, xu, 1, calls/5, r, s,
                                     &res, &err);
        }
      while (fabs (gsl_monte_vegas_chisq (s) - 1.0) > 0.5);

      gsl_monte_vegas_free (s);
      gsl_rng_free (r);


return res;
}
```

Comment: What function do you want to integrate? Why do you want to use Monte Carlo? Why do you want  to parallelize this integration at all? Is it an academic task or real-world problem?

Comment: It is a real-world problem. I thought to parallelise it to speed it up. But may be it is not the best strategy. I think that the reason why it is slow is because the integral has difficulty to reach convergence. `Composite_at_t` is the function to integrate.

Comment: The integrand looks to be a sum. What happens if you set `n_lim = 1`? Perhaps this integral of a sum can be easier to treat as a sum of integrals. Another point: the integrand looks like Fourier transform or so.   Will it help if you restrict the domain of integration to just 1 period? GSL & Boost surely use automatic-step-control functions based on Richardson extrapolation. They need kinda smooth integrands to converge, while you present them with chaos.